# ADB Cannot show my device after the first command

Tags: android, debugging, adb

I am running Android Platform tools for MAC OSX. when I connect the android device and execute

**./adb device**

it list my device. If I tried to run something later like

**./adb shell ????**

it runs the command then the device is no longer available and I have replug in the USB Cable.

I am using the latest Platform Tools for MAC OSX. I do not have such problems when I tested the device on my laptop which runs Windows.

any hint?

Comment: If your not opposed to using an IDE I have found that intellij has nice support for android development, it may fix your issue.

Comment: I am using Eclipse already. but I had to use ADB command to check why the device is first detected then disappears. And found that the first command executes successfully while later commands fails.

Comment: Has nothing to do with the IDE